# mod_rewrite worked and now doesn't

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I created a new apache2 server. Htaccess loads and works but I can't seem to get .php to not show. The page will go to 404 instead of loading the php version.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php 
</IfModule>

<Files ~ "\.tpl$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Update: I moved this to apache.conf instead of htaccess. Same problem though

Comment: Solved it by changing it to: Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews